# Ubuntu 19.10 freeze/hang/crash while trasfering data from hard disk to pc

Tags: freeze, 19.10

I am using ubuntu 19.10 the latest version of ubuntu. I am facing a lot of problems while transferring data from pc to my Seagate 2TB hard drive or in vice-versa.The system hangs a lot or some time freezes right away.I hope someone will get a solution for me.

System Details

DELL-G3
8GB RAM
Intel® Core™ i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8 
NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1050 4GB GRAPHICS
Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)